# Place space or dash between number

Tags: php

I have number `123456789`.
I want to place - between two number till my given number count would not be end.

```
$nubmer = 1234567890.
```

output will be `12-34-56-78-90`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: have you tried using the `preg_replace` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function splitNum($num) {
  return implode("-", str_split($num, 2));
}
echo splitNum("1234567890") //output: 12-34-56-78-90
```

Comment: for your last word get plus 1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the number to string and split it into equal part of `2`. then implode them. Conversion is not mandatory but good for perfect result.

```
$nubmer = "1234567890"; //OR $nubmer = 1234567890;
$arr = str_split($nubmer, 2);
echo implode("-", $arr);//12-34-56-78-90
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the Manual for information on `str_split` and `join`

```
<?php
 $number = 1234567890;
 $split = str_split($number,2);
 echo join('-',$split);
?>
```

Comment: this is hilarious is what it is

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple one liner [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) - Wraps a string to a given number of characters:

```
<?php
$number = 1234567890;
echo wordwrap($number, 2, '-',true);
```

output:

```
12-34-56-78-90
```

Comment: I always forget about wordwrap

Answer (score 0):

"One-line" solution using `chunk_split` and `trim` functions:

```
$nubmer = "1234567890";
$splitted = trim(chunk_split($nubmer, 2, "-"), "-");  // contains "12-34-56-78-90"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php